# Objective C Generating (empty) WAV file

Tags: objective-c, core-audio

I'm trying to save some audio data to a WAV file -- I have audio data that normally I've been using in RemoteIO but I'm now trying to implement a function to save the data.  I know the audio data is valid, so that's not a concern -- if I can just get an empty WAV file set up of the correct length, I can fill it with data later.

Right now, the code creates the file and it looks to be the right length in bytes, but apparently it's not formatted correctly, because OSX, QuickTime, iTunes, etc can't recognize it (they see the file, can't determine a length, or play it)

```
    NSURL * tvarFilename = [savePanel URL];
    NSLog(@"doSaveAs filename = %@",tvarFilename);        

    //try to create an audio file there

    AudioFileID mRecordFile;

    AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
    audioFormat.mSampleRate         = 44100.00;
    audioFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags        = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 2;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 16;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = 4;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = 4;



    OSStatus status = AudioFileCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)tvarFilename, kAudioFileWAVEType, &audioFormat, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &mRecordFile);

    int beatsToRecord = 4; //temporary

    int bpm = 120;

    double intervalInSamples = (double) 60 / bpm;
    intervalInSamples *= (double)44100;

    int inNumberFrames = (intervalInSamples * beatsToRecord);

    UInt32 frameBuffer[inNumberFrames];

    int sampleTime = 0;

    UInt32 thisSubBuffer[inNumberFrames];

    for (int i = 0; i < inNumberFrames; i++) { frameBuffer[i] = 0; }

    UInt32 bytesToWrite = inNumberFrames * sizeof(UInt32);
    status = AudioFileWriteBytes(mRecordFile, false, 0, &bytesToWrite, &frameBuffer);
```

Comment: You should examine your files with a hex editor and see how they differ from the standard.

Comment: Yeah -- I think that's my next step.  Diving into it now

Comment: Okay, looks like the issue is the header -- the rest of the data is being written correctly.

So, in other words the AudioFileCreateWithURL() call is what's causing the main issue, it looks like

Comment: AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
    audioFormat.mSampleRate         = 16000.00;
    audioFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags        = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 1;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 16;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = 2;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = 2;

This works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WAV file is really simple: it only consists of a (usually 44-byte long) header section, then the raw PCM data. I've written a library which needs to record WAV files, and I'm pretty sure you'll understand how I accomplish it. For clarifying:

```
/**
 * CD quality: 44100 Hz sample rate, 16 bit per sample, 2 channels (stereo):
**/
struct sprec_wav_header *hdr = sprec_wav_header_from_params(44100, 16, 2);
int filesize = (obtain the filesize somehow here);
/**
 * -8 bytes for the first part of the header, see the WAV specification
**/
hdr->filesize = filesize - 8;
int filedesc = open("/tmp/dummy.wav", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
if (sprec_wav_header_write(filedesc, hdr))
{
    printf("Error writing WAV header!\n");
}
close(filedesc);
free(hdr);
```

And the library I've written: https://github.com/H2CO3/libsprec/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks -- I've started scanning your code.  There has to be a way to do it with AudioFileWriteBytes, though, right?  Isn't that what the function is there for?

Comment: the AudioFile API is only really useful when you want to seriously integrate it to AudioUnits, AudioQueues etc. so the lower-level CoreAudio APIs. In case you just wanna create an empty WAV file, it's really not worth it. As even you yourself stated, you'll be able to fill it in later using a method that fits you best.

Comment: What do you mean not worth it?  It seems like, if I iron out whatever parameter I have incorrect, I'll have a 1 line function to write the audio, whereas in your code you use many.  I'm willing to write in the extra code, but that leave more lines to debug later, etc.  Seems like almost the opposite would be true

Answer (score 1):

The problem in code in initial question was in missing `AudioFileClose(mRecordFile);` line in the very end.

For those who still search for working sample without using 3rd party libraries, here is slightly modified code snippet:

```
- (void)createSilentWAVFileAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL {
    AudioFileID mRecordFile;

    AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
    audioFormat.mSampleRate         = 44100.00;
    audioFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags        = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 2;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 16;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = 4;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = 4;

    OSStatus status = AudioFileCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)fileURL, kAudioFileWAVEType, &audioFormat, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &mRecordFile);

    double intervalInSamples = 0.5;
    intervalInSamples *= audioFormat.mSampleRate * audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;

    int beatsToRecord = 4; //seconds of silence
    int inNumberFrames = (intervalInSamples * beatsToRecord);

    UInt32 frameBuffer[inNumberFrames];

    for (int i = 0; i < inNumberFrames; i++) { frameBuffer[i] = 0; }

    UInt32 bytesToWrite = inNumberFrames * sizeof(uint32_t);
    status = AudioFileWriteBytes(mRecordFile, false, 0, &bytesToWrite, &frameBuffer);
    status = AudioFileClose(mRecordFile);

    NSAssert(status == noErr, @"");
}
```

P.S.: To decrease final file size reduce `mChannelsPerFrame` from 2 to 1 and `mSampleRate` (e.g. to 11000)