# How to generate an empty .wav file (duration = 0, no silence/blank .wav) in ffmpeg?

Tags: audio

### Background

We need to generate silence wav in our logic, and using the following ffmpeg command:

```bash
ffmpeg -f lavfi -t $duration -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=48000 -y $output
```

All is ok untile we got a excetion in production environment:

```bash
Error generating silence audio, length: 0, target: xxxx.wav, 
error: av_interleaved_write_frame(): No space left on device 
[wav @ 0x681fb80] Filesize 1258523197518 invalid for wav, 
output file will be broken Error writing trailer of
```

As in previous log, it's because `-t 0` will cause the ffmpeg generating **unlimited file untile it blows up the disk** when `$duration == 0`, then exception.

### Question

1. Why `-t 0` generate unlimited-length audio instead of a `duration=0` wav?
2. And how to generate a epmty `.wav`/audio file in ffmpeg.

> PS, I found it [Objective C Generating (empty) WAV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464669/objective-c-generating-empty-wav-file) , but I want do do it in ffmpeg. I only get the `silence generating` questions and haven't search any question about duration=0. May be it's too rare to meet in real condition?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Comment: Now I can't delete it. how about remove the tag?

Comment: The tag is not what makes your question off topic. Try voting to close

Comment: I really think it's a valuable quesion and it really cause bug in production. May be it should be moved to some other place, but now I can't delete it or vote down it. Just let it be.

Comment: Someone else will come along and delete this eventually. It has no place here. ffmpeg questions are not allowed.

Comment: SELF NOTES: you can use `AudioSegment.empty` to generate empty audio if you use Python with `pydub`.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you a WAV with no audio data.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc -bsf noise=drop=1 empty.wav
```

If you plan to append media later on,

1. make sure your anullsrc attributes match that of the data you will be appending (channel layout, bit depth..etc). Basically the header  that ffmpeg writes should match the ultimate payload.
2. Note the offset of the 4th byte from the end. The 4 bytes starting there store the byte size of the PCM data in little endian order. It will be zero in the file generated above. Replace it after you are done appending.

Comment: It really produce empty wav. Thanks. May be some explaination? And It still need to process the edge condition of duration == 0. I don't know why `-t 0` can't produce result as expected.

Answer (score 1):

the -t 0 directs lavfi to create a 0 seconds.
the anullsrc has no explicit duration.
for some reason, ffmpeg chooses the undefined length of anullsrc and enters an endless stream rendering that ends when the disk is full due to the huge file size.

add a zero duration instruction to anullsrc, here's your command with the modification:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -t $duration -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=48000:d=$duration -y $output
```

btw - 0 duration is not recommended, since there are no audio samples written into $output.
silence means samples at 0 amplitude.
if no audio is rendered into the file it is hard to predict what will happen later in the process you're intending using this file.

Comment: You even don't see overall question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).